# Lipschitz function in $L^2(\Omega)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, lipschitz-functions

I read a statement in a paper and I do not think it is correct.

Let $X = L^2(\Omega) \times L^2(\Omega) \times L^2(\Omega)$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a smooth bounded domain. For $u = (f,g,h) \in X$ define $G(u) = (fg, fh, gh).$

Is $G: X \to X$ Lipschitz?

In my opinion, it is not simply because $fg$ might not even belong to $L^2.$ And even if it does, the Lipschitz estimate does not work.

Am I correct?

Comment: Could you provide a link to said paper? This does indeed look false as is though, it's just to see if there's more context.

Comment: You are using the notation $g$ for two different things ...

Comment: @LL3.14 thanks, I corrected it now.